# Has any traction been made on the case to rename the field of philosophy?

Tags: history-of-philosophy, ontology

There was a NYTimes article a few years back where Colin McGinn proposed "Ontics" as a more precise name for the field of philosophy.

https://opinionator.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/03/04/philosophy-by-another-name/

Wondering if this was part of an actual movement or if this went anywhere?

Comment: Considering that McGinn's ideas about "scientific" nature of philosophy and its lack of concern with human culture would exclude most of what philosophy is generally seen to include I am not sure that even McGinn was taking his own proposal seriously (publishing it in NYT is another sign of that). See [“Ontics” vs. Philosophy](https://peripateticpraxis.wordpress.com/2012/03/05/ontics-vs-philosophy) and [Re-branding Philosophy?](https://dudeexmachina.wordpress.com/2012/03/09/re-branding-philosophy) responses.

Answer (score 2):

### No.

It's hard to give evidence for a total lack but of existence because there's nowhere to point, but, like, google it. There's nothing. Ontic is already a word with a distinct meaning, and the Campaign for Renaming Philosophy turns up only four relevant results.

And I think the article was really just supposed to be taken as a tongue-in-cheek complaint of being lumped together with ethicists, aestheticians, and similar.

Comment: Also, the article is written by McGinn after all, so you'd think he'd be all for a little "mystery" about philosophy - but I suppose he wants ontics to be a ["new" mystery](http://www.consciousentities.com/mcginn.htm)...